# UPDATE Sql cannot have aggregate in set

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's the work around to this error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

I've looked at a few examples but not really sure.

This is what I have now:

```
 UPDATE UserAnswer 
 SET userId = (SELECT id FROM Users WHERE id=max(id)) 
 WHERE userId = NULL
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? What database - you tagged both MemSQL and Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement  that's the error and also it is microsoft sql. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a variable, like this:

```
DECLARE @maxId INT;

SELECT @maxId = MAX(id)
FROM Users;

UPDATE UserAnswer
SET userId = @maxId
WHERE userId IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks this was the solution by selecting first and assigning it to variable.

Answer (score 3):

This may solve the issue, you need to make the max in the select list.

```
UPDATE UserAnswer 
SET userId = (SELECT Max(id) FROM Users) 
WHERE userId is NULL
```

Comment: sorry tried this can't do aggregate functions such as Max.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **MAX** OR **Order By**:

**MAX:**

```
UPDATE UserAnswer 
SET userId = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Users) 
WHERE userId = NULL
```

**Order By:**

```
UPDATE UserAnswer 
SET userId = (SELECT TOP(1) id FROM Users Order By id DESC) 
WHERE userId = NULL
```